# Filepicker Drag-Drop Widget Size

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a way to specify the size of the default drag-drop pane for:

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop"/>
```

Ideally I want something like the larger Javascript drag-drop pane with a button for manual uploading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data-fp-drag-class` property. You'll just have to define your own css class.
https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#widgets-drag

http://jsfiddle.net/66z9K/

Comment: How do we prevent filepicker.io from outputting its default js? I'm not keen on having to override every style with !important to achieve the styling a project may require.

Comment: Hi Larry. We put reasonable defaults on it and since we don't have access to the page, we do element styling, which is fairly high up on the CSS priority level, which is probably why you need the important. Email me at liyan@filepicker.io and let me take a look at the style sheets you want to apply. If it's onerous, we should take a look at wiping default css if the class is specified.

Comment: Hi Liyan. Ye, the problem lies with the injected styles having higher specificity than the class. The ideal situation would be for filepicker.io to not inject any styles when a class is specified. It's a bit confusing at the moment, as I expected when adding a class that only that class' styles would then be applied, and no inline styles would be present. We'll go ahead with @brettcvz 's answer, and the use of !important, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913124/filepicker-io-web-disable-inline-styles for now. I hope wiping styles will come under consideration! Thanks Liyan.